# The final field cannot be assigned, for an interface

Tags: java, interface

I have a class Product and an interface LargeProduct. Product implements LargeProduct.

LargeProduct has a variable height which has getter and setter methods which have to be implemented in the Product class.

The height variable in LargeProduct is defined like so:

```
public int height = null;
```

The getter method works fine:

```
public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}
```

But the setter method does not:

```
public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}
```

Errors:

```
The final field LargeProduct.height cannot be assigned
The static field LargeProduct.height should be accessed in a static way
```

I'm not sure which error it's actually giving.. I'm using Eclipse and when I hover it gives the first error, and at the bottom of the window it gives the second error.

Comment: An interface defines the contract between a caller and a callee. Methods and constants are part of that contract, not fields. (If it were you wouldn't need a getter or setter)  If you want a parent to define a field, use an abstract class.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Interfaces can only include *constants*, not general-purpose variables. Interfaces should *only* contain constants if they're genuinely relevant to the rest of the interface, and they should use `SHOUTY_CASE` as per any other constant. It sounds like `LargeProduct` *shouldn't* have a constant called `height` - but instead, your implementation should declare the `height` field.

Note that interfaces are meant to be APIs, showing the abilities of types. Fields shouldn't be part of the API - they're an *implementation* detail. After all, who's to say that you'll write `getHeight` and `setHeight` based on a simple variable? Those methods could query a database, or delegate to an instance of some other type. The consumer of the interface shouldn't know or care about that.

For further information about fields in interfaces, I suggest you read [section 9.3 of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3):

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public, static, and final. It is permitted to redundantly specify any or all of these modifiers for such fields.

Comment: What?! So I can't store certain variables for certain interfaces?

Comment: @Jon final is the key issue here Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438228/the-final-field-cannot-be-assigned-for-an-interface/4438277#4438277

Comment: @org.life.java: No, that's a *symptom* of the bigger issue, IMO - which is not understanding the distinction between API and implementation. A normal field is an implementation detail - it should generally be private, and shouldn't be part of the API. Even if the field weren't implicitly final, it would still be implicitly *static* which would still cause issues. Basically a "field" within an interface is a constant, and should only be thought of as a constant.

Comment: @Jon thats true in terms of concept & design ,pattern but for compiler its  _final_

Comment: @org.life.java: I think it's most important to understand the concept - at which point the details follow naturally :)

Answer (score 3):

By default fields (member variable) in interface are **public static final**

and you don't have setter for *final*

Answer (score 2):

> The height variable in LargeProduct is
>   defined like so:
>
> ```
> public int height = null;
> ```

Variables defined in interfaces are implicitly `static` and `final`, i.e. constants. That's what the compiler complains about.

You cannot define an instance variable in an interface. Just leave it out - the get and set methods ensure that the classes can be used as intended. The actual variable is an implementation detail if the implementing classes.

Comment: This is the crux - interface variables are _implicitly_ `final`. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value to a final field. Declare height in Product as

```
private int height;
```

Comment: @Matt: It's implicitly final though, because it's declared in an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly org.life.java! And you cannot modify a static final variable! Because it's the way to determine a constant in Java.